Foundation 6 accordion deep-linking with smudge offset appears to not be working
I am implementing some Foundation 6 Accordions which can be opened automatically by the deep-linking functionality and using the data-deep-link-smudge="true attribute to automatically adjust the position of the linked Accordion item. However, it appears that this functionality is not working correctly and I am trying to determine / confirm that this is an issue with Foundation 6 and not just an issue in own code. (Foundation 6 has been around for a while at this point so it's possible that a bug is occurring with modern browsers).
In an attempt to confirm this I have created a basic example to test using the following markup within a page set up with the appropriate Foundation JS and CSS files referenced and set up for deep-linking as per the Foundation 6 docs.
Here is the basic markup I've used for the Accordions:
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-deep-link="true" data-deep-link-smudge="true" data-deep-link-smudge-delay="500" id="deeplinked-accordion">
    <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#deeplink1" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content id="deeplink1">Panel 1. Lorem Epsom dolor</div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#deeplink2" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content id="deeplink2">Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </li>
</ul>

Here's a link to a test page I have set up, this should open the 6th accordion and scroll to its  position on the page:
https://qreate.co.uk/test-accordion.html#deeplink6
Can anyone confirm that this is also not working correctly for them?
